# for IIS, should i use Win7 or Server 2012r2?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012-r2

Ill need to set up a test IIS.

From a rapid research, ive found that Win7 and Server 2012r2 are pretty much offering the same (for IIS purposes).
Major difference is supported RAM and parallel RDP sessions.
Rather than that, relying on the fact i need IIS, which one is the right OS ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Depends on what you're testing. If you can accept that your testing environment doesn't mirror your production environment just use the cheaper solution - I guess that's the real point behind this: "Do we need to spend money on a server license or would a simple workstation OS do?".

Comment: Generally you are right, since its a test (1 person use) station, for test deployments etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the same at all. Windows 7 uses IIS 7, whereas Windows Server 2012, uses IIS 8. Plus, Windows 7/Windows 8 are *consumer class* OSes. They're not intended for running things like web servers. Likewise, Windows Server 2012 is kind of inappropriate as something like a development machine.

If you're talking about "test" in the sense of QA/staging server, then you should use an actual server class version of Windows. If you're talking about a machine to do development on, then you can stick with something like Windows 7 or 8, but then, you shouldn't even be worry about IIS. You'd just have Visual Studio and run everything through IIS Express.

Comment: "If you're talking about "test" in the sense of QA/staging server, then you should use an actual server class version of Windows"       That answered my Question, thanks !